# Autofac IComponentRegistration

Tags: autofac

We're using autofac and I noticed the RegisterComponent method off of ContainerBuilder.  I couldn't find any examples of it's usuage, is this meant to be used by client code?  If so, any examples on how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegisterComponent is primarily useful for lower-level Autofac support/extension, like if you're creating a custom registration source that builds component registrations manually. If you search the Autofac source code you can find uses of it.

Generally speaking, most client code will not use that method.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Are you saying I could hook in at a lower level to change the way parameters are matched?

Comment: Autofac is exceptionally flexible and has a lot of places where you can hook in. The original question doesn't talk about parameter matching at all - there's a whole separate mechanism for handling parameters. Rather than get into it here I'd recommend: First, [go check out the doc site](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/) because there are lots of examples; then go look at [the source](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac) and unit tests for even more examples. If things still aren't clear, open a new question with more detail about what you're trying to do.